# How to add categories related to legend in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I've almost finished my graph except one problem. I want to link each unique series with legend and categories. I want to put a number under each chart and these numbers will be shown in the legend. So let me explain visually.

Here is what I've done:

[image]

And here is what I want to do:

[image]

See? It always put `0` in the bottom? But I want to put separate number for each bar like in second one.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TBCd4/) .

I didn't want to do with pure HTML because I concern about *positioning*.

**PS:** I've already tried `categories: [1,2,3,4,5]` but it's no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that categories dont work for you is that you have specified 5 series with 1 datapoint, whereas the categories relate to 5 datapoints. If you specify your data like this:

```
var data = [{data:[
    {
        x:1,y:6793,name:'lorem',pname:'some explanation',chid:9,color:'red'
    },
    {
        x:2,y:4237,name:'ipsum',pname:'some explanation',chid:7
    },
    {
        x:3,y:3384,name:'dolor',pname:'some explanation',chid:23
    },
    {
        x:4,y:2542,name:'sit',pname:'some explanation',chid:1
    },
    {
        x:5,y:724,name:'amet',pname:'some explanation',chid:1
    }
]}
];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z5VPw/

you can get it to work as there are 5 categories and 5 datapoints.

I had to modify your function to iterate over the points, not the series:

```
$.each(chart.series[0].points, function (i, series) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set categories as you posted,

http://jsfiddle.net/yTFTb/

```
xAxis: {
            categories: [
                '1',
                '2',
                '3',
                '4',
                '5'
            ]
        },
```

or set min/tickInterval values for xAxis.

http://jsfiddle.net/yTFTb/2/

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.min
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval